# Importing data from excel to multiple tables in Oracle DB

Tags: excel, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have an excel sheet with a single workbook with data in it. The data is around 1000 rows and 50 columns. I need to import these data to an Oracle DB every week. Here comes the problem, the columns in the sheet belongs to different tables with some columns go in multiple tables. I use SQL Developer V.18.1.0.095. Thanks in advance for the help.

Note: I created a temp table and copied all data to it, then wrote the query to push each column to its respective tables. But, I feel its complex and think it won't work. Is there any better way.

Comment: code ? What have you tryed ?

Comment: @xoxel I created a temp table and copied all data to it, then wrote the query to push each column to its respective tables. But, I feel its complex and think it won't work. Is there any better way.

Comment: Use CSV instead, post files to server. Add a job that does insert as selects from the CSV using External table feature

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PL/SQL Developer` has special tool for tasks like this, calls `ODBC Importer` (Menu 'Tools'-> ODBC Importer).
For use it you have to set Excel File in `USER / System DSN` field and your domain user and password, and push `Connect` after.
After connection developer will ask you path of excel file, and after you can create table in heiborhood tab for your dataset.

Or, you can use `sql loader`. Ask google how to. It's easy.

Comment: How to do the same in `Oracle SQL Developer` ?

Comment: Which one version of PL/Sql Dev. do you have?

Comment: I have Oracle SQL Developer 11g Version 18.1.0.095 and not PL/SQL Developer.

Comment: Have you tried this way? http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/sqldev/r30/SQLdev3.0_Import_Export/sqldev3.0_import_export.htm